# JSTL tag importing generic way

Tags: jsp, jstl

This is my project structure

[image]

Main JSP is the container JSP  ,where I am replacing different div .Now I am using JSTL tags ,but to do that it is asking to  add lib tags in every JSP .

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Can't I do this in generic way . I tried importing in container(main) JSP , its not working . Can't I handle it with web.xml  file or anything else please help .

Comment: You could replace these 2 lines of code by one line using a static include.

Comment: can u please show how . in code

Comment: Google is your friend. Google for "JSP static include" and read.

Comment: not working with static include.